# Mysql group by date part of datetime and select rows with max datetime for each date

Tags: mysql, datetime, group-by

My data looks like,

Table - usr_weight

| user_id | weight | log_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | 10 | 2021-11-30 10:29:03 |
| 1. | 12 | 2021-11-30 12:29:03 |
| 1. | 11 | 2021-11-30 14:29:03 |
| 1. | 18 | 2021-12-01 08:29:03 |
| 1. | 12 | 2021-12-15 13:29:03 |
| 1. | 14 | 2021-12-15 17:29:03 |

Here, I have duplicates for each date with different time. So, group date and return the record with max time for each date.

**Query**

```
select weight, log_time from usr_weight where user_id = 1 group by DATE(log_time)
```

Here, I get 1 record for each date, but the row is not by max(log_time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER` we can try:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(log_time)
                                 ORDER BY log_time DESC) rn
    FROM usr_weight
    WHERE user_id = 1
)

SELECT user_id, weight, log_time
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Here is an old school join way of doing this:

```sql
SELECT uw1.user_id, uw1.weight, uw1.log_time
FROM usr_weight uw1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT DATE(log_time) AS log_time_date, MAX(log_time) AS max_log_time
    FROM usr_weight
    WHERE user_id = 1
    GROUP BY DATE(log_time)
) uw2
     ON uw2.log_time_date = DATE(uw1.log_time) AND
        uw2.max_log_time = uw1.log_time
WHERE
    uw1.user_id = 1;
```

Comment: You are so incredibly fast! It's inspiring to see you write multiple solutions within seconds/minutes.

Comment: @zedfoxus LOL...I'm on a cell phone right now.  Would have been much faster on a laptop.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen where condition to be added on the with query.

Comment: I have added the `WHERE` logic.